# Angular text ng-minlength when NOT empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to force ng-minlength to be a conditional value?  For example, I want a user to either enter their proper middle name or nothing at all:

```
<input type="text" id="middleName" name="middleName" 
       ng-model="info.middleName"
       ng-minlength="info.middleName ? 2 : 0">
```

The syntax above does not work.  An 'infinite loop' error is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="middleName" name="middleName" 
  ng-model="info.middleName"
  ng-pattern="/^(?:.{2,})$/">
```

This uses a regular expression to do the same. The `2` is the minimum length. After the comma is the maximum length (infinite, since there isn't anything).

Comment: This would be the cleanest solution..but if there is validation then it should change to `form.middleName.$invalid` +1

Comment: More specific would be form.middleName.$error.pattern

Answer (score 1):

`ng-minlength` only takes in static values. If you are looking for a custom solution, try creating your own directive using the `$observe`. Therefore, to answer you question, no it is not possible to force `ng-minlength` to be a conditional value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This is also more readable

```
<input type="text" id="middleName" name="middleName" 
   ng-model="info.middleName"
   ng-minlength="getMinLength(info.middleName)">
```

In the javascript file:

```
$scope.getMinLength = function getMinLength(dataModel) {
    //whatever your model is...
    return dataModel ? 2 : 0;
}
```